# Open chrome://newtab from a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I try to write a Google Chrome extension that simply opens a new tab when I click left-right in a short interval. The JavaScript is no problem but I implemented this as a "content_scripts" script.

In some other threads I read that I can't access the chrome.* APIs from content_scripts (except the chrome.extension API).

Even if it's not necessary to access the chrome.tabs API to open a new window (window.open should do the job) it seems I need it though for opening a new tab *with the new tab page* which obviously isn't possible via window.open.

So I can't really figure out what is the best way to do that. I could use a background page which I could call from the content_script but I think there *should* be a much more simple way to do that, I just don't get it.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your content script will have to send a message to your background page to invoke `chrome.tabs.create` - content scripts cannot use the chrome api, nor can they directly communicate with the background page.

Here's a [reference](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) about message passing inside Chrome extensions for further detail, but here's the example code ( modified from the example in said reference )

```
// in background
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch ( request.action) {
       case 'newTab' : {
         //note: passing an empty object opens a new blank tab, 
         //but an object must be passed
         chrome.tabs.create({/*options*/}); 
         // run callback / send response
       } break;
    }
    return true; //required if you want your callback to run, IIRC
  });

// in content script:
chrome.extension.sendMessage({action: "newTab"}, function(response) {
  //optional callback code here.
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I thought about using event pages but I didn't manage to get them into my brain (maybe the time, 2am over here in Germany). ;-)

But that still makes Chrome giving me a notification about a background page that started. That's actually no problem for me but I guess this page will keep running also if Chrome is closed, which is absolutely unnecessary for an event page...

Comment: @user2048874: Background page will live per session, and will stop when a session is closed.

Answer (score 1):

simple and easy

```
document.body.onclick = function openNewWindow(  ) {
  window.location.href = 'javascript:void window.open( "chrome://newtab" )';
}
```

manifest:

```
,"permissions":[
    "http://*/*"
    ,"https://*/*"
  ]
  ,"manifest_version": 2
  ,"content_scripts":[{
    "matches":[
      "http://*/*"
      ,"https://*/*"
    ]
    ,"js":[
      "js/openWindow.js"
    ]
  }]
```

alright i miss understanding the question... modified

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I need to do. As I said I specifically want to open the Chrome New Tab Page which is chrome://newtab and which is not possible via window.open().

Comment: I think I like this solution better than mine - not having to monkey around with message passing is a plus.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but this still isn't working.
Maybe I should just describe the problem - a window IS opened (I tried it the same way like you first) but Chrome won't open the New Tab Page from window.open() but an about:blank page. That's the whole problem. :-)